# Complicated: Error uncompressing data from a packet stream zlib

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flash, compression, zlib

I have a incoming stream that is compressed using the zlib functions, but I cannot tell the ending of the compressed data, so am having a lot of trouble getting the data out.

I also have a snippet of the source code where it is being uncompressed in AS3 flash, which should have been enough for me to figure it out, but I am at a loss.

Two files included:

http://falazar.com/projects/irnfll/version4/test//stackoverflow/as3_code.as.txt
  http://falazar.com/projects/irnfll/version4/test//stackoverflow/bin_data_file

Snippet of the binary data, and what I know:

```
00 00 02 34 2c 02 31 78 5e ed dc cd 6e da 40 a5
21 19 40 f5 f2 c4 b7 e9 18 85 e1 5b 89 66 3d 42
31 95 90 cd 15 74 99 55 37 51 14 59 c9 a8 8c 54
```

0234 appears to be a size marker - 564

2c = 44, the code to match as3 COMMAND_WORLD_DATA, that is ok

0231 another size marker, always 3 smaller than above

785e - is the header marker for the zlib compress weakest compression, ZLIB_ENCODING_DEFLATE level 4

Later there is also a 789c which is another larger compressed block

I need to uncompress the two of these to move forward in project, thank you for your help.

There is also mention in the script of bigendian conversion, and am I not sure if I need to handle that.

I have written a couple scripts to try and solve this, including a php snippet that chops off the end until and loops trying to uncompress with no luck.
  falazar.com/projects/irnfll/version4/test//stackoverflow/php_test.php.txt

Ideal solution in php or c#, but anything I can see that works will translate into another language easy enough.

(Using Free hex editor nero to view the binary)

Answer (score 1):

You mean [zlib](http://zlib.net/).

Use [PHP's `gzuncompress()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gzuncompress.php) starting at each zlib header (e.g. `789c`).

Comment: Straight from the source, great.
Zlib yes of course.


I changed out and use that function, can test that it works fine with a sample text string, but still no luck on the binary data.


I have several source files I am testing now, a couple using the 785e level and some using the 789c level.


Can you use the data and get anything workable from it?  I am not sure which part is messed up.  The code works from the server using the as3 code but I cannot seem to use the data.  Thanks.